# Not able to navigate dynamically inside a lazy loaded module - Angular Dynamic Routing

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-routing, dynamic-routing

I'm trying to route dynamically inside a lazy loaded module. But it's not working.

lazymodule-routing.ts

```
 {
    path: "city",
    component: CityComponent,
    children: [{ path: "/:name", component: NameComponent }]
  }
```

component.ts

```
 <div *ngIf="showCities">
   <mat-nav-list  *ngFor="let city of cities" >
     <a [routerLink]="['', city.name]" mat-list-item>
       {{city.name}} <img src="{{city.country_flag_url}}" />
     </a>
   </mat-nav-list>
 </div>
```

I want it to navigate to the NameComponent, but it doesn't.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: try `[routerLink]="['/', 'city', city.name]"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either of these methods:

1.) `[routerLink]="['city', city.name]"`

2.) `[routerLink]="['./', city.name]"`  - Relative Path